# Android NPE with Admob Interstitial Ads

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, admob

I've update my app adding Google Admob Interstital ads, they works perfect on my device and emulator, I don't get any error, I've tried everything to make the app crash but didn't happen.

This is the error shown on Google Play Developers Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.myapp.android/com.google.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2815)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.android.f.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.ads.b.w.q(Unknown Source)
at com.google.ads.AdActivity.h(Unknown Source)
at com.google.ads.AdActivity.onPause(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5106)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1225)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2846)
... 12 more
```

The users says that the crash happens when they close the ad, this is my onDismissScreen method:

```
@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) {
 showInterstitial = false;
 launchChapter(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext());
}

private void launchChapter(Context c) {
 boolean extPlayer = Settings.getSettingPlayer(c);
 boolean extCheck = Settings.extCheck(c);
 boolean saveView = Settings.getSettingChapterView(c);

 if (saveView == true) {
  String vid = cid.replace(getString(R.string.chapter) + " ", "");
  Settings.setChapterView(c, pid + "_" + vid, true);
 }

 if (extPlayer && extCheck)
  new GetSources().initExternal(getString(R.string.url) + url, c);
 else {
  Intent intent = new Intent(c, Player.class);
  intent.putExtra("ID", cid);
  intent.putExtra("URL", url);
  intent.putExtra("TITLE", title);
  intent.putExtra("SCREEN", screen);
  startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Notice that 'com.myapp.android.f' is a fragment.

Comment: It would help if you deobfuscated your stacktrace. How else would we notice that com.myapp.android.f is a fragment? Once you deobfuscate the stack trace, your should be able to see where the NPE is occurring.

Comment: What line is the NPE happening on?

Comment: @SkyKelsey Because I see on the mapping file com.myapp.android.ChFragment -> com.myapp.android.f.

Comment: @Blaine ProGuard isn't configured to show the line where the NPE ocurrs.

Comment: You should reconfigure proguard to stop hiding line numbers. Right now, you would be able to see the exact line that is throwing the NPE if not for that configuration.

Comment: @SkyKelsey yes, that's what I have done, also re-done all again the launchPlayer() method, the bug appear again on the developer console and now seems to be because the fragment isn't attached when onDismissScreen executes, I've added an if with this.isAdded() to check that, the problem is that the user might need to click twice.

Comment: I'm not quite following you. If you have better information, please post it. Post more code, post a deobfuscated stack trace, etc.